# Solving a quadruple integral of view factor

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm solving an analytical quadruple integral in *Mathematica*, but the app can't solve it. I don't know if it is because that I do a bad formulation of the integral or maybe, *Mathematica* is not able to do this.

I divided the quadruple integral into two double integrals. So actually, *Mathematica* solves the first double integral, but when I put the result into the second, the app doesn't solve it.

I don't know how to write the integrals here, that's why I attached a photo.

[image: Quadruple Integral]
[image: First double integral]

Comment: I have tried indefinite integral with `Integrate` and the 3rd-party [`\`Rubi\`Int`](https://rulebasedintegration.org/), both of which are successful.

Comment: You do not need actually the 4-integral. The 2-integral you typed is sufficient. Just do the substitution $a=x-u$, $b=x+u$ in the original integral. The integration over $b$ is trivial. Analogically you do with $y$ and $v$ variables.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'm running with Rubi, but I'm not having good luck. I'm new in mathematica. On the other hand, I don't understand the cv that you made it, you mean in the 4-integral?